# PHP won't execute if there is 2 WHERE conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I am trying to get my PHP to execute this script that inserts data from one table into another but with 2 WHERE conditions, "userID" `AND` "confirmation" but it is only working if I set only 1 WHERE condition i.e `WHERE confirmation = :confirmation`.

I need to have a `AND` so that the script only affects the individual session user (userID) rather than all users.

I tried using a comma instead of `AND` but still nothing.

I also tried typing them like `userID = '$userID' AND confirmation = :confirmation` but still nothing.

```
$charizard = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (email, first_name, last_name, product, quantity, date, price)
(SELECT email, first_name, last_name, product, quantity, date, price FROM checkout WHERE userID = :userID AND confirmation = :confirmation)");
$charizard->bindParam(':userID', $userID);
$charizard->bindParam(':confirmation', $confirmation);

if ($charizard->execute())
{
  $delete_stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE FROM checkout WHERE userID = :userID AND confirmation = :confirmation");
  $delete_stmt->bindParam(':userID', $userID);
  $delete_stmt->bindParam(':confirmation', $confirmation);
  $delete_stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: The field name could be incorrect, the PHP variable could be empty. If the SQL execcute is failing what is the SQL error / response?  Did you turn on PHP errors to get the PHP errors?  Did you echo the PHP values to make sure they made sense?

Comment: @DaveS I know its working because when I only use one WHERE condition it works fine, its only when I add the `AND userID = :userID` then it doesnt work

Comment: That's the case that you need to be debugging: the PHP variables, PHP errors and warnings, SQL errors and warnings -- all when you have the AND.

Comment: @DaveS is that like using `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION` I've used this in my code many times before and it makes no difference to anything...